# How can i add square brackets to json, after converting from xml, using java

Tags: java, json, xml

I have the following code with me.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class Xml2Json {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String xmlString = "<users><user name=test1 age=20></user><report sub=eng score=30></report></users>";
        JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
}}
```

It produces the following output:

```
{"users":{"report":{"sub":"eng","score":30},"user":{"name":"test1","age":20}}}
```

But what I actually need is with square brackets only one some of the tags/elements, as you can view on below JSON as expected output:

```
[{"users":[{"report":[{"sub":"eng","score":30}],"user":{"name":"test1","age":20}}]}]
```

Comment: `"user":{"name":"test1","age":20}` why this is not included in list? it should be like this `"user":[{"name":"test1","age":20}]` as per your output

Comment: @deadshot  Actually, it is not the complete code.. and there are some segments which is not included in the list.

Comment: my question is why value of `user` is not included in list? but `report` is included in list why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class XmlToJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xmlString = "<users><user name=test1 age=20></user><report sub=eng score=30></report></users>";
        JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
        jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").put("report",new JSONArray().put(jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").getJSONObject("report")));
        jsonObject.put("users",new JSONArray().put(jsonObject.getJSONObject("users")));
        JSONArray jsonArray =  new JSONArray().put(jsonObject);
        System.out.println(jsonArray);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[{"users":[{"report":[{"sub":"eng","score":30}],"user":{"name":"test1","age":20}}]}]
```

Comment: I have just solved his/her homework or he is learning the code. I have not solved this as a generic one because the result what he wants is not generic, some of the variables are only converting from JSONObject to JSONArray.

Comment: I am not talking about generic solution even if the single key name changes your code will not work

Comment: If single key name changes than definitely their reference must need to change. e.g. if "report" is changed to "reports" then their references in code need to change from "report" to "reports" as well.

Comment: @Ashish Karn.. Thank you anyways..just as u said, am learning code and it means lot.

Comment: @my_doubt Is solution provided by me correctly? If you let me anything more than let me know else accept and upvote the answer. Thanks, Keep Learning a program every day.